# How to convert a map with coordinates to a graph/adjacent list/adjacent matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I want to convert a map to a graph/adjacent list/adjacent matrix.

For instance, suppose I have a map with @ mark represents inaccessible walls and number represents nodes:

```
@@@@@@@
@12  5@
@@@3@@@
@4    @
@@@@@@@
```

The node coordinates:

```
1: (1, 3)
2: (2, 3)
3: (3, 2)
4: (1, 1)
5: (5, 3)
```

The output of this problem should be a graph like this:

```
1-2-5
  \ /
   3
   |
   4
```

1 can only connect to 2, as 2 is the only node that 1 can reach without passing other node. 2 can connect to 1, 3 and 5, the same reason as above.

The walls and nodes coordinates are given. I want an algorithm to convert any given map to a graph like the one above. Can anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: Run bfs from a node and see which other nodes it can access directly. Then from those nodes, do the same. This approach should be O(n) time.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to find the connections between the digits in the map, even if they are not directly adjacent to each other:

```
from functools import reduce as rd
s = """
@@@@@@@
@12  5@
@@@3@@@
@4    @
@@@@@@@
"""
#convert the map to a coordinate dictionary
coords = {(k, j):b for j, a in enumerate(filter(None, s.split('\n'))) for k, b in enumerate(a)}
def to_graph(start, seen = []):
   t_coords = [lambda x, y:(x+1, y), lambda x, y:(x+1, y+1), lambda x, y:(x, y+1), lambda x, y:(x-1, y), lambda x, y:(x-1, y-1), lambda x, y:(x, y-1)]
   #find possible valid squares to consume
   if (ops:=[k for f in t_coords if (k:=(f(*start))) in coords and coords[k] != '@']):
      #recursively check possible squares
      results = [to_graph(i, seen+[start]) for i in ops if i not in seen]
      vals = rd(lambda x, y:{**x, **y}, results, {}) #merge results
      return {coords[start]:vals} if coords[start].isdigit() else vals

print(to_graph((1, 1))) #start with coordinates of any value
```

Output:

```
{'1': {'2': {'5': {}, '3': {'4': {}, '5': {}}}}}
```

The output returns a dictionary showing the relationships between the values as positioned in the map: `1 -> 2, 2 -> (5, 3), 3 -> (4, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, that works even if some nodes are not connected at all with the others, and a bit less memory costly :

```
def getNodes(l):
    a={}
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            if (type(l[i][j]) is type(1)):
                a.update({l[i][j]:(i,j)})
    return a

def searchAdjascentNodes(m,coordonates):
    nodes=set()
    old=set()
    toDo=set([coordonates])
    while (len(toDo)!=0):
        discoveredVertices=[]
        for i in toDo:
            adjascent=[j for j in [(i[0],i[1]+1), (i[0],i[1]-1), (i[0]+1,i[1]), (i[0]-1,i[1])] if (j[0]>=0 and j[0]<len(m) and j[1]>=0 and j[1]<len(m[0]) and j not in old and j not in toDo and j not in discoveredVertices)]
            for a in adjascent:
                if(type(m[a[0]][a[1]]) is int):
                    nodes.add(m[a[0]][a[1]])
                elif(m[a[0]][a[1]]==' '):
                    discoveredVertices.append(a)
        old=toDo.copy()
        toDo=set(discoveredVertices)
    return nodes

def createGraph(m):
    n=getNodes(m)
    r={}
    for i in n:
        r.update({i:searchAdjascentNodes(m,n[i])})
    return r
```

You can run it like this :

```
theMap=[['@','@','@','@','@','@','@'],['@',1,2,' ',' ',5,'@'],['@','@','@',3,'@','@','@'],['@',4,' ',' ',' ',' ','@'],['@','@','@','@','@','@','@']]
print(createGraph(theMap))
```

And you get :
`{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3, 5}, 5: {2, 3}, 3: {2, 4, 5}, 4: {3}}`